# Unable to run multiple spec files at a time using protractor

Tags: jasmine, protractor

To run multiple spec files using Protractor i have tried below 2 methods. none of them works.

1. I changed the "Protractor configuartion" file as below.

   specs: [
   './/e2e//Profiles//AdditionalInfo//Certifications//cert_opt_selection-spec.ts',
   './/e2e//Profiles//AdditionalInfo//Certifications//cert_creation-spec.ts'
   ],

and use the below command

```
ng e2e
```

2.From the command prompt i used below command.

```
ng e2e --specs='.//e2e//Profiles//AdditionalInfo//Certifications//cert_opt_selection-spec.ts' --specs ='.//e2e//Profiles//AdditionalInfo//Certifications//cert_creation-spec.ts'
```

Can any one help me how to execute multiple spec files at a time in protractor

Answer (score 0):

Modify your config file with below capabilities object,

```
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'maxInstances' : 2 // will split your test files across 2 browser instances
    'shardTestFiles': true,
}
```

If you want to run it on different browsers, You need to use `multiCapabilities` instead of `capabilities`. Refer https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/parallel-test-execution-protractor-sudharsan-selvaraj/ for additional details on multiCapabilities.

Comment: thanks for your reply ..after modification of configuration file , the two spec files running . but the problem is in my 1st spec file i wrote code to select an option from the drop down . in my 2nd spec file i wrote a code to create a record for the selected option .. but by using above after completion of first spec execution the browser closes and 2nd spec execution opens new browser. i just want to execute my two specs in one browser continuously.. is there anyway ???

Comment: does your 2nd spec file depends on 1st spec?